# Offsite Incremental Encrypted Backups for a small law office

Tags: encryption, backup

I am the system administrator for a small law office.

We have a local file server on our network that holds all of our digital records.

I currently have this server being incrementally backed up nightly to one of the local machines using `rsync`. (Basic method: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/rotating-snapshots)

We would like to improve this system in the following ways:

1. Host a backup offsite
2. Encrypt the backup.

It would be very nice if the backup could be incrementally updated, so we don't have to upload 10 - 100GB every time we backup.

Is there any way to do incremental encrypted backups to a remote server? We have a small budget for solving this problem, if necessary.

Comment: Could be more on topic on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)...

Answer (score 2):

Any of the myriad cloud backup providers (Backblaze, Carbonite, Mozy, etc.) have business/server plans that will give you an offsite incremental backup option, and many (if not all) provide the ability to use encryption with keys you control, which is of course critical for data as sensitive as legal documents.

Some things I would specifically look for:

- Encryption on the client side, prior to upload, so unencrypted data never leaves your environment
- Encryption using well known, standard, proven mechanisms that are well described.  You don't want to rely on YOLO crypto, and you should not have to guess about how your data is protected.
- Encryption using keys you control.  The provider should not have access to the keys, and thus the ability to decrypt your data
- Should provide key management considerations, like the ability to securely store keys in an HSM or TPM, and possibility the ability to rotate keys to prevent overuse.

There are many other factors of course, but these are a few of the most critical security considerations when considering off-site backup options.

Comment: what is "YOLO crypto"? the same as "RYO crypto"?

Comment: @dandavis It's similar, ("You only live once...") and can certainly incorporate rolling your own.   In retrospect it's probably too slangy a term, but implies crypto that isn't properly thought out or carefully implemented.